# URL Rewrite Sub-domain and Directory Structure in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite/redirect a url in ASP.NET 4.0

Example:

***Requested URL***:
http://www.domain.com/accounting/blog/post/2009/07/17/Getting-the-most-out-of-your-account-firm.aspx

***Rewritten/Redirected URL***:
http://blog.domain.com/post/2009/07/17/Getting-the-most-out-of-your-outplacement-firm.aspx

In other words, change the sub-domain from "www" to "blog", and remove "/accounting/blog" from the directory structure, then redirect.

Here is the rule I am using (passes pattern matching tests in IIS, but does not work):

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="blog redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.domain\.com\/accounting\/blog\/(.*)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://blog.domain.com/{C:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules></rewrite>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for any domain:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="blog redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^accounting/blog/(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://blog.{C:1}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```